# Linux software to detect my keyboard layout

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

My keyboard has a button with the signs: ">" and "<". This button types "`" and "~" instead. It's located up to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> button. There are also 2 more messed up buttons.

Anyways I don't know "the name" of my keyboard layout so I need to identify its type. I need some software to help me with that.

I remember when I was installing Ubuntu, there was a software that asked me to press certain keys to detect the keyboard type. Is there a similar software?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/384758/10425

Comment: I saw that long ago. It doesn't have an answer. Thanks anyway :) @moose

Comment: the software that does that is called 'keymapper'. I don't yet know how to start it in its visual mode. When I found out I'll post an answer. (google: ubuntu keymapper)

Answer (score 2):

Credits to Martin Thoma for the link to AskUbubtu

Count the number of keys on your keyboard, and type (or paste) this in the terminal.

`~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

This command reconfigures a package called "keyboard-configuration" with administrative privilege (in case it's needed). So, this will reconfigure your keyboard layout manually (not automatically).

Tips:

- In my case, a generic 104 keys keyboard worked! (Because my external keyboard doesn't appear in the list, but it has 104 keys, excluding upper multimedia and internet browsing keys)
- If you have the "Alt Gr" key, this will make a huge difference.
- If you are in Spain or Latino América (or if you use a *tilde*) choose the "include dead tilde" option. It's called "dead" because once you pressed it, it doesn't do anything, but it defines the character of the next pressed key. Just like `Alt Gr`.